# Using generic method and generic object for generating different cover type values

Tags: c#, generics, memorystream

I have a generic method for generating different insurance cover types. `CoverType` is a generic object.

```
public class CoverType<T>
{
    public Func<T, string> Values { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Asset { get; set; }
}

public interface IGenerateCoverTypeService
{
    Stream GenerateCoverType<T>(CoverType<T> coverType, IEnumerable<T> coverValues);
}

public Stream GenerateCoverType<T>(CoverType<T> coverType, IEnumerable<T> coverValues)
{
    if(string.IsNullOrEMpty(coverType.Name))
        return null;
    
    var sbCoverValues = new StringBuilder();
    sbCoverValues.AppendLine(coverType.Name);
    foreach(var values in coverValues)
        sbCoverValues.AppendLine(coverType.Values(value));
    return new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sbCoverValues.ToString));
}
```

I am trying to get the insurance cover types values stream in the Motor Insurance page using the below method.
**MotorInsurance.cs**

```
public Func<CoverType<MotorInsuranceCover>> GetMotorCoverTypeDefaults { get; set; }
.
.
private async Task GetMotorCoverDetails()
{
    var coverTypeDefaults = GetMotorCoverTypeDefaults();
    var ms = coverTypeService.GenerateCoverType(coverTypeDefaults, coverValues);
    .
    .
}
```

`MotorInsurance.cs` pass `CoverType<MotorInsuranceCover>` motorcovertype as input

```
Name:"Motor Cover",
Values: of type CoverType<MotorInsuranceCover>
```

`MotorInsuranceCover` object has the following values

```
Asset:"Car"
ID:"MERC25BT1521RN02015A"
Desc:"2015 MERCEDES-BENZ C250 BLUETEC 205 "
PriceNew:45500
PriceRetail:35000
Year:"2015"
Make:"MER"
Type:"4D SEDAN"
```

The expected output is a stream of string values which is an input to a print function.

The above function is not working and I am not getting expected result stream when a motor cover type is passed.

The error I am getting is - CoverType requires 1 type arguments

Can anyone help.

Comment: "The above function is not working and I am not getting expected result stream" And what **is** the expected outcome? What is your input and what do you get instead?

Comment: I have updated the input/output in the question

Comment: Why does `GenerateCoverType` need to know that the output is a UTF8 stream? IMHO you should rework your api so that each text generator receives a `TextWriter` argument and writes the result into it. Then it should be possible to send that input directly to your print function without buffering anything.

Comment: For me I am getting error at the generic type itself